# Creating new Dict from values of another

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "SKzSjdBuOpO49wkPVaxtmLQoR0O2": {
        location: "-LB1fn5GQKTaIc-fGNPS"
    }, 
    "s0ntSZP7mBQw1a8ua0E5PqazlqJ2": {
        location: "-LB23izD7bp2NhO0UuIo"
    }, 
    "FEScjelpNSR7vuVz1ha6Z6uSfF43": {
        location: "-LB1JLABuJO1NyJ-v2t_"
    }, 
    "mW7dGja6cRRB0d9uSIhg4f35PzC3": {
        location: "-LB5xqUvIjEgtW_FH_nG"
    }, 
    "GCnt0VKcqjT8bl2chw43nsntaZK2": {
        location: "-LB1n8ga9C0vCcZXD2Us"
    }
}
```

in my `Values[String: Any]` dictionary. And i want to Create another dictionary from its values to access location value.
Can you help me to do this?

Comment: So you're primary goal is to access the location values?

Comment: @LukasWürzburger yes, i want to get location values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary goal is just to access the values and the type is fixed to `[String: Any]`, do it like this:

```
if let info = dictionary["SKzSjdBuOpO49wkPVaxtmLQoR0O2"] as? [String : String] {
    let location = info["location"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `Dictionary` in swift, rather for your case you can use `[String : [String: String]]` type and then loop through you data to get the required values. Try this

```
  let dict = ["SKzSjdBuOpO49wkPVaxtmLQoR0O2": [
        "location" : "-LB1fn5GQKTaIc-fGNPS",
        ], "s0ntSZP7mBQw1a8ua0E5PqazlqJ2": [
            "location" : "-LB23izD7bp2NhO0UuIo",
        ], "FEScjelpNSR7vuVz1ha6Z6uSfF43": [
            "location" : "-LB1JLABuJO1NyJ-v2t_",
        ], "mW7dGja6cRRB0d9uSIhg4f35PzC3": [
            "location" : "-LB5xqUvIjEgtW_FH_nG",
        ], "GCnt0VKcqjT8bl2chw43nsntaZK2": [
            "location" : "-LB1n8ga9C0vCcZXD2Us",
        ]]

    var newDict = [String: String]()
    for (key, val) in dict {
        newDict[key] = val["location"]
    }
    print(newDict)
```

Output:

> ["SKzSjdBuOpO49wkPVaxtmLQoR0O2": "-LB1fn5GQKTaIc-fGNPS",
>   "s0ntSZP7mBQw1a8ua0E5PqazlqJ2": "-LB23izD7bp2NhO0UuIo",
>   "FEScjelpNSR7vuVz1ha6Z6uSfF43": "-LB1JLABuJO1NyJ-v2t_",
>   "mW7dGja6cRRB0d9uSIhg4f35PzC3": "-LB5xqUvIjEgtW_FH_nG",
>   "GCnt0VKcqjT8bl2chw43nsntaZK2": "-LB1n8ga9C0vCcZXD2Us"]

### Edit

For your case as you have dictionary, you can try this:

```
   let dict = ["SKzSjdBuOpO49wkPVaxtmLQoR0O2": [
        "location" : "-LB1fn5GQKTaIc-fGNPS",
        ], "s0ntSZP7mBQw1a8ua0E5PqazlqJ2": [
            "location" : "-LB23izD7bp2NhO0UuIo",
        ], "FEScjelpNSR7vuVz1ha6Z6uSfF43": [
            "location" : "-LB1JLABuJO1NyJ-v2t_",
        ], "mW7dGja6cRRB0d9uSIhg4f35PzC3": [
            "location" : "-LB5xqUvIjEgtW_FH_nG",
        ], "GCnt0VKcqjT8bl2chw43nsntaZK2": [
            "location" : "-LB1n8ga9C0vCcZXD2Us",
        ]] as Dictionary<String, Any>

    var newDict = [String: String]()
    for (key, val) in dict {
        if let value = val as? [String: String] {
            newDict[key] = value["location"]
        }
    }
    print(newDict)
```

Comment: The problem is, that i have [String: Any] model that comes from Firebase in that look. And i cannot have location with parentheses  :(